# Why Doesn't My Component Appear On Top of The HTML Page Or Media Player In Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I've used a media player and I'm trying to do rendering on top of it with progress indication or buttons but the code isn't working.

E.g.:

```
findInfiniteProgress().setVisible(true);
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
               @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(findMediaPlayer().getMedia() != null && findMediaPlayer().getMedia().isPlaying()){
                    findInfiniteProgress(f).setVisible(false);
                    }else{
                    findInfiniteProgress(f).setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One uses lightweight rendering which means all components are drawn in sequence on a single thread. Native widgets (peers) need to be drawn on the native thread and are always drawn on top, that is the secret to Codname Ones portability explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html).

Common peers in Codename One include: Web browser, media playback & native maps.

The workaround is to use `Dialog` which is effectively a separate `Form` so the current peer doesn't really render underneath.